# matrix multiplication using arrays gives me wrong answer

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply a 3x4 and a 4x2 matrix and output a 3x2 matrix to the screen. For some reason I am getting the last row wrong, but the first two are correct.

I've tried changing my conditions

```
    int result[6];
    int rows=3;
    int columns = 2;
    int mvalue=4;
```

but still got the wrong answer.

`mvalue` is supposed to be the middle value of the matrix size which is 4 in this case (3x**4** × **4**x2).

```
void multiMatrix(int matrix1[], int matrix2[], int result[], int rows, int columns, int mvalue){

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
            result[i*columns+j]=0;
            for(int w=0; w<mvalue; w++){
            result[i*columns+j]= result[i*columns+j]+matrix1[i*columns+w]*matrix2[w*columns+j];
            }
        }
    }


}

#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int matrix1[]={1,2,3,4,
                    1,2,3,4,
                    5,4,5,3};
    int matrix2[]={1,2,
                   3,4,
                   1,2,
                   3,4};

    int result[6];

    int rows=3;
    int columns = 2;
    int mvalue=4;

    multiMatrix(matrix1, matrix2, result, rows, columns, mvalue);
     for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){

          std::cout<<result[i*rows+j]<<" ";

        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

}
}
```

The output should be:

```
22 32
22 32
31 48
```

The actual output I am getting is:

```
22 32
22 32
1  2
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Have you tried cutting down the input data to find a smaller example of it going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computing line should be this:

```
result[i*columns+j] += matrix1[i*mvalue+w]*matrix2[w*columns+j];
```

Also, when you print out the values, you should be printing out

```
cout<<result[i*columns+j]<<" ";
```

instead of

```
cout<<result[i*rows+j]<<" "; // i * rows is squaring itself
```

Answer (score 1):

You index both *matrix1* and *matrix2* by doing `something * columns + something`

This cannot be right, because matrix1 and matrix2 have different shapes. In one case the multiplication should be by 4, and it should be by 2 in the other.

I'll let you debug from there.